# How to use a capture from a rewrite rule inside a php file (like single.php)?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, single

My rewrite rule to make a convenient url for deep-linking into podcasts

```
add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", function($rules) {

    $newRules = array();

    $newRules["(.*)/time/([\d|\:]+)s?$"] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&t=$matches[2]'; 

    $merged = array_merge($newRules, $rules);

    return $merged;

});
```

Query Monitor shows me this rewrite rule is working; I get to single.php with the right post, Woop Woop!

But `$_GET["t"]` is not set. I also don't see a `t` in `$wp_query->query_vars`. How can I now make use of `t` inside the `single.php`?

.

.

What confuses me: 
My rewrite rule for `/email` works similar; but `email.php` can make use of the get-vars;

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^email/(.*)/(.*)/?$',
    'wp-content/themes/myTheme/email.php?to=$1&subject=$2',
    'top'
);
```

Comment: You have to introduce the variable with `add_query_var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicolais Tip got me on the right track; Here is the working code:

```
// add a query_var first
add_filter("query_vars", function($vars) {
    $vars[] = "myTheme_podcast_time";
    return $vars;   
});

add_filter("rewrite_rules_array", function($rules) {

    $newRules = array();
    $newRules["(.*)/time/([\d|\:]+)s?$"] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&myTheme_podcast_time=$matches[2]'; 

    $merged = array_merge($newRules, $rules);
    return $merged;

});
```

And then in `single.php`:

```
$time = get_query_var("myTheme_podcast_time");

// do stuff
```